# Help with complicated construction of tables

Tags: tables

I am writing my undergraduate project in Latex, and I have a few tables to write. However, they are not simple, aligned tables. Here is an example:

[image]

I have written a code the produces something similar, but would like to know if there is a more constructed way. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cl}
\begin{tabular}{cl}
$a$&$a$\\
\hline
1\qquad 1 &\hspace{0.3cm} 1\\ 
2\qquad 2 &\hspace{0.3cm} 2\\ 
3\qquad 4 &\hspace{0.3cm} 3\\ 
4\qquad 3 &\hspace{0.3cm} 4\\ 
5\qquad 3 &\hspace{0.3cm} 5\\
6\qquad 3 &\hspace{0.3cm} 6\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Moreover, if I would like to know how I can underline two elements in different columns. For example, in the last row, the element 3 and the element 6 **of the last column**?

I would be grateful to hear your opinion.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Secondly, please don't post external links because if they disappear, say next year, you question will be meaningless. Instead, include in the image with your question.

Comment: @Andrew, thank you. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to write such tables is probably to have separate columns for the headers. For example, a table like the one in the question but with some missing entries could be typeset as:

```
\begin{tabular}{*5c}% 5 columns, all centered
    &a& &a& \\\hline
   1& &1& &1\\
   2& &2& &2\\
   3& &4& &3\\
   4& &3& &4\\
   5& & & &5\\
   6& & & &6\\
\end{tabular}
```

This produces the lefthand table below:

[image]

For the righthand table is exactly the same except that I have used the column specifications `{c*4{@{\space}c}}` in order to make the table more compact (the `@{\space}` says that the space between the columns is a `\space`, and the `*4` says that the column specification `@{\space}c` is repeated four times).

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{*5c}% 5 columns, all centered
        &a& &a& \\\hline
       1& &1& &1\\
       2& &2& &2\\
       3& &4& &3\\
       4& &3& &4\\
       5& & & &5\\
       6& & & &6\\
  \end{tabular}
  \qquad
  \begin{tabular}{c*4{@{\space}c}}% more compact version
      &a& &a& \\\hline
     1& &1& &1\\
     2& &2& &2\\
     3& &4& &3\\
     4& &3& &4\\
     5& & & &5\\
     6& & & &6\\
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you want to "globally" change the spacing between the columns in a `tabluar` environment then you could add the command

```
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.5mm}
```

to your preamble (being `\begin{document}`). With the two tables above are close to identical.

Finally, if the entries in the tables are "mathematics" then you should use `array` environments`instead of`tabular` -- the syntax is the same except that the environments should be enclosed in math-mode, and the output will be slightly different as the entries of the tables will also be typeset in math-mode. In fact, as you want to underline some entries then is probably what you want. For example, to produce

[image]

you can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  \renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{0.5mm}
  \[
  \begin{array}{*7c}
      &a& &a& &b&\\\hline
     4& &3& &4& &4\\
     5& & & &5& &5\\
     6& & & &\underline{6}& &\underline{7}\\
  \end{array}
  \]

\end{document}
```

To have the underline stretch across several columns you can, as mentioned already in the comments, use `\cline`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  \renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{0.5mm}
  \[
  \begin{array}{*7c}
      &a& &a& &b&\\\hline
     4& &3& &4& &4\\
     5& & & &5& &5\\
     6& & & &6& &7\\\cline{5-7}
  \end{array}
  \]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

This works with both `array` and `tabular` environments. Notice that the line produced by `\cline` is slightly lower than that produced by `\underine{...}` so if, for example, you wanted to underline just the entry in column `5` for consistency it would be better to use `\cline{5-5}` -- this also involves less typing and gives you a better layout for the typed table! In addition, you can use several `\cline` commands on one line: `\cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}` will add two lines under columns 1-3 and 5-7.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it's more complicated than that. Thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Tea Sorry, noticed that I didn't address the underlining question. Have just done this. See the last example.

Comment: @Andrew: I'd rather use `\midrule` for some padding of the horizontal line.

Comment: @Andrew. Thank you for adding the answer about underlining. Since I need to have an underline stretching from the number 6 to the number 7(including both of them) in the example, I thought of using the command cline. What do you say?

Comment: @Mr.Tea Yes, that works. I have added an example.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for the explanation and the example. It really helps a lot. I appreciate it! Thank you.